# Comment appelle-t-on une personne qui repousse ses limites ? (Mentales /positifs)

Tags: grammaire, expressions, adjectifs

Repousser ses limites mentales , au-dessus de la normale et des gens environnants.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que l'on dise repousser ses limites. On parle de dépasser ses limites.....repousser serait un contresens ici. Les limites s'étendent. Verbe: étendre. repousser les limites voudrait dire: ne pas le reconnaître. Et finalement, on dit les gens autour de soi. Pas les gens environnants.

Comment: @Lambie [*repousser ses limites*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/repousser_ses_limites) se dit de plus en plus. Quand on dépasse ses limites, on en établit de nouvelles donc on a bien repoussé les anciennes.

Answer (score 1):

**Transcender quelqu'un** : Le dépasser en lui étant supérieur. *Le Professeur, investi d'une autorité de type spécial, transcende le groupe* (Le Nouvel Observateur, 30 juin 1969, p. 21, col. 1). *Il transcende tous les autres par son intelligence* (GDEL).

**Se transcender** : Se dépasser en allant au delà de ses possibilités. *Jamais nous ne vîmes un tel nombre de poètes et jamais l'écriture n'eut davantage l'idée fixe de se transcender et de se vêtir dès le matin en robe du soir* (Cocteau, Poés. crit. II, 1960, p. 209).

Et donc l'adjectif :

**Transcendant** : Qui s'élève au-dessus d'une limite, d'un niveau donnés; qui s'élève au-dessus du niveau moyen. 
Synononyme : excellent, esprit supérieur, intelligence, mérite, pensée, talent, virtuosité transcendant(e); connaissances, études, recherches transcendantes. 
*Que Bonaparte fût un homme d'un génie transcendant à beaucoup d'égards, qui pourrait le nier ?* (Staël, Consid. Révol. fr., t. 2, 1817, p. 103)

Source : Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales (CNRTL)

Par ailleurs, le **perfectionniste** s'attache à se surpasser lui-même chaque jour. (faire toujours mieux) C'est une personne qui croit au progrès illimité, à la perfectibilité de l'homme, à la perfection.

Answer (score 0):

On peut suggérer [téméraire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/t%C3%A9m%C3%A9raire) et [audacieux](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/audacieux).